# Multiple WPF MediaElements doesn't work properly

Tags: .net, wpf, video

I just want to know  why 2 video doesn't work at the same time? Only 1 video plays and the second doesn't. But there is a sound of the second video... That's odd! Any clue? Thanks!

```
 <Grid>
        <MediaElement Height="299" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
        <MediaElement Height="299" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,0,0,0" Name="mediaElement2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
    </Grid>
```

UPDATES:

As I found it works like I said under DEBUG mode of Visual Studio only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing 2 videos in WPF is NOT an issue. How are you loading the videos?

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("Content\\Wildlife.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
        mediaElement2.Source = new Uri("Content\\Wildlife.wmv", UriKind.Relative);

        mediaElement1.Play();
        mediaElement2.Play();
    }
```

Just make sure that the video path is correct.

If you add the the video in your project make sure it has the following properties set:

- Content
- Copy if newer

Comment: Hey! The path is correct. :) It happens only when I debug an application. When I execute EXE there is no problem. Thanks!